# Why does the shape of a numpy array distort after appending an element from another numpy array with same shape?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays, A with shape (70, 2048) and B with shape (11200, 2048).
I want to append an element at index i from B to A, so I do:

```
A = np.append(A, B[i])
```

After this, the shape of A is suddenly (145408,). When I look at `B[i].shape` I get (2048,). I guess this is why the shape of A changes, but how do I actually append B[i] to A? So that I get what I want, a numpy array with (71, 2048).

I feel like I don't understand something very fundamental about this, it would be great if someone could help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you've jumped into using the function without paying much attention to the documentation.  `np.append` is a poorly named and conceived function.  It is not a list append clone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy is first flattening the two arrays so that it can take the [i]th element from B and append it to the end of A.  There's no other way to append a single element onto a multi-dimensional array.

You can read more about it in the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html#numpy.append).  Judging from your question, what you may want is to specify an `axis` argument so that this flattening doesn't happen.

Docstring from the `axis` arg.

```
The axis along which values are appended. If axis is not given, both arr and values are flattened before use.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried specifying the axis argument, but with either axis = 0 or axis = 1, I got the error that the first argument has 2 dimensions and the second only has 1 dimension. Is there really no way to achieve what I want? I thought this would be an ordinary use case.

Comment: You want to use `np.vstack`.  The underlying function for joining arrays is `np.concatenate` (look at your error message), but it is picky about the dimensions of the arrays.  `np.stack` takes care to make sure the arrays are at least 2d.  Soon or later you need to understand array dimensions!